# Prove Euler totient $\phi(p^k)=p^k(1-\frac{1}{p})$ with group theory?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, ring-theory, totient-function

Of course, this can be counted using elementary means. I'm just curious if there is any connection to group theory techniques or results such as those related to $p-$groups or cyclic groups.

Comment: There is a problem in your question because $\phi(p^k)$ is the size of the unit group of the **ring** $\Bbb{Z}/p^k\Bbb{Z}$ (which is also the endomorphism ring of the cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}/p^k\Bbb{Z}$). For $p$ odd prime $\Bbb{Z}/p^k\Bbb{Z}^\times$ is cyclic. The elementary proof is saying that for $\gcd(n,p^k) = 1$ then the multiplication by $n$ has trivial kernel which implies it is an automorphism thus a unit of the endomorphism ring.